# Javascript: defining a new protorype that would replace document.getElementById() with document.findId()

Tags: javascript, prototype

What I'm trying to do is to create a prototype function which could be used like a shorter version of document.getElementById(); which would look kile this: document.findId(); This method would return the same value as if I used  regular getElementById()
Lets say I've done something like this:

```js
Element.prototype.findId = function (value) {
   var element = document.getElementById(value);
   return element;
};

var something = document.findId('some_id');
alert('Id is: ' + something);
```

I know this example is not gonna work but what would be a good way to achieve this?

Comment: but why should you do that? the name is even shorter, but the meaning of the name is different

Comment: document is an instance, adding to the prototype gains nothing, just `document.something=` will do, there is only 1 instance of document after all..

Comment: I would like to experiment with finding and returning values of elements... Now i got to work with prototypes. I just want to know how i would define such prototype function.

Comment: in this way you are not adding a function to any prototype. You are adding a method to the `document` instance

Comment: In general, yes this might work, but `document` is a `Document` instance not an `Element` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply just copy the function.

```
document.findId = document.getElementById;
```

Full example:

```js
document.findId = document.getElementById;

document.findId('something').innerHTML = "<b>Hello, world!</b>";
```

```html
<div id="something"></div>
```